# Array not inputting data from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I'm trying to make an array with the structure like so:

```
[ 
    { 
        "ips": 
             "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx", 
             "yyy.yyy.yyy.yy",
             "zzz.zzz.zzz.zz" 
        "ai": 
             "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx",
             "yyy.yyy.yyy.yy"
    } 
]
```

So I can check if variable with string is inside array. But I'm collecting the IP's from a DB using mysql, and am not sure how to insert the  IP's.

I've tried this:

```
$whitelist = array(
    'ips' => array(), 
    'ai' => array()
);

// sql command
$sql = "SELECT `ip` FROM `testers`";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    array_push($whitelist['ips'], 
        $row
    );
}
```

Can somebody please tell me how I can do this/ Seriously so lost other then inserting the IP's individually. That would take forever and not easy to track.

Comment: That's not a valid PHP array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your solution is really close. You just need to access the row that you retrieved from mysql as an associative array using `$row['ip']`.

The below code should save the ip's from the database to the $whitelist['ips'] array and then print the results to the screen.

```
$whitelist = array(
    'ips' =>array()
);
$sql = "SELECT `ip` FROM `testers`";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    array_push($whitelist['ips'], $row['ip']);
}
var_export($whitelist);
```